# quick way to extract "valid" substring in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory, c-strings

I wrote two functions to extract a "valid" substring from a string, which means the substring may only contain letters and numbers. However I'm not too thrilled with the fact that they start losing performance if the string to check is lengthy, even if the performance gap isn't too noticeable. Is there a faster way to "validate" the string? Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <wchar.h>

wchar_t* validstr(wchar_t* src, wchar_t* cc, unsigned int* index) {
    wchar_t* valid = calloc(1, sizeof(wchar_t));
    while (isalpha(*cc) || isdigit(*cc)) {
        valid = realloc(valid, (wcslen(valid) + 2) * sizeof(wchar_t));
        wcscat(valid, (wchar_t[]) { *cc, 0 });
        ++* index;
        *cc = src[*index];
    }
    return valid;
}

wchar_t* validstr2(wchar_t* src) {
    wchar_t* valid = calloc(1, sizeof(wchar_t));
    while (isalpha(*src) || isdigit(*src)) {
        valid = realloc(valid, (wcslen(valid) + 2) * sizeof(wchar_t));
        wcscat(valid, (wchar_t[]) { *src, 0 });
        src++;
    }
    return valid;
}

int main() {
    wchar_t* str = L"valid10+(notvalidanymore";

    // usage for validstr()
    wchar_t current = str[0];
    unsigned int index = 0;
    printf("%ls\n", validstr(str, &current, &index));

    // usage for validstr2()
    printf("%ls\n", validstr2(str));
}
```

Comment: realloc inside a loop will be very slow.  Why not just find the number of valid characters with a loop and then allocate the space and copy the data after the loop?  Is there a reason you need to realloc inside the loop?

Comment: I'd just [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) the string and then move all characters that shall remain towards front, skipping those that are irrelevant. If you absolutely want to keep the allocated memory minimised, then count the remaining characters first.

Comment: @Aconcagua  His code doesn't keep all valid characters - it just keeps the inital substring up to but not including the first invalid character.  So he could strdup the string and then replace the first invalid character with a string terminator.  That seems a good way to do it - if there is a wide-character version of strdup.

Comment: This is what I was thinking: https://onlinegdb.com/qg24aTzxo  It still has to loop but it only increments inside the loop so the performance isn't really an issue because the time is completely eclipsed by the calloc.  Actually, calloc seems a waste - you don't need to initialize the memory if you are immediately going to write over it.  What about https://onlinegdb.com/gCvppGSBO

Comment: @JerryJeremiah My fault, have been inattendent. On POSIX, there's [`wcsdup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wcsdup.3.html) and seems as if windows supports it as well. Admitted, no guarantee to be generally portable...

Comment: You could use `wcsspn` to count the number of characters up to the first invalid character. You just need to supply a string containing list of acceptable characters.

Comment: `isalpha` and `isdigit` should not be used on `wchar_t` values, per C 2018 7.4 1, which says the argument shall be the value of `EOF` or an `unsigned char`. Use `iswalnum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid re-allocations as far as possible.

So you might first count the characters that are of relevance for you:

```
size_t length = 0
for(wchar_t* tmp = cc; *tmp && iswalnum(*tmp); ++tmp)
{
    ++length
}
```

Note that there is `isalnum` function covering both alpha and digit – but you should use the wide character function in any case (`isw[...]`, note the additional `w`).

Once you've counted, you'll just copy those values that are of interest:

```
wchar_t* valid = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
//                                ^ terminating null character!

memcpy(valid, cc, length*sizeof(wchar_t));
valid[length] = 0;

// for validstr:
memcpy(cc, src, length*sizeof(wchar_t));
*index = length;
```

I prefer here `malloc` over `calloc` as there's no need to zero-initialise the array, it is overwritten anyway.

Note that above version for `validstr` differs slightly from your implementation: *You* increment first, then copy the character, which skips the very first character of `str`. My version starts copying at the very first character. If skipping first character actually was intended, then copy from first character on and you are fine again:

```
memcpy(cc, src + 1, length);
```

Be aware that this version (`validstr(wchar_t*, wchar_t*, unsigned int*)`) does not appear pretty safe to me anyway, you might easily read beyond the bounds of src, which would result in undefined behaviour – unless you always guarantee by whatever means that `src` is at least as long as the substring copied.